# Opencart .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am pretty new to OC and am running the latest version. I am ready to open up my site to the (potentially) many hundreds of people whom I hope will have a look, like something and then buy it!
My problem is the last bit, being the the security of the site before I launch it
I have read the 3 pages of good ideas for website security and I am a little confused.
Can some explain in quite easy terms what I need to do and an idiots guide on how to do it. I would like to make my site as secure as possible,or at least as much by a newb possibly can without wrecking it.

Comment: Don't use OpenCart if security is a requirement.